# Sorting a TXT file in Java

Tags: java, sorting, text

I have a Method i used to extract info from a website and have it currently going to TXT files. I am looking to sort the information out similar to how it is displayed in the output when I do a print statement to show results as shown below:

```
 QB 3 Anderson, Derek ACT TDS -- INT -- YDS -- RTG 0.0 CAR
 QB 2 Barkley, Matt ACT TDS 0 INT 4 YDS 300 RTG 44.6 PHI
 QB 5 Bethel-Thompson, McLeod ACT TDS 0 INT 0 YDS 0 RTG 0.0 SF
```

In my text file I have it shown as:

```
QB3Anderson, DerekACTTDS--INT--YDS--RTG0.0CARQB2Barkley, MattACTTDS0INT4YDS300RTG44.6PHIQB5Bethel-Thompson, McLeodACTTDS0INT0YDS0RTG0.0SF
```

Any Suggestions (Please note this is in Java)

Comment: How can you tell where one quarterback ends and the next one begins?

Comment: The deeper problem seems to be how you are extracting the information from the website. How are you doing that?

Comment: I am extracting it using JSoup

Comment: Basically I would like to sort it out to the way it is in the output when I compile it because it will make it easier to add the necessary info im extracting into my DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read each line using a BufferedReader. Each line will be a string. Then add each line to a list and sort the list.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
    String line;
    ArrayList<Entry> list = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(new Entry(line));
    }
    Collections.sort(list);

    // list is sorted!
```

Then you need the Entry class:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {

    private String qb;
    private String number;
    private String name;

    public Entry(String text) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("", " ");
        this.qb = st.nextToken();
        this.number = st.nextToken();
        this.name = st.nextToken();
        // ... etc
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entry other) {
        return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
}
```

Your class needs to implement Comparable so that Collections.sort() will know how to sort. Also, implementing equals() and hashCode() is always a good idea.

Comment: Pretty sure this would sort the list by the quarterback's number. I think the OP wants to sort them by name.

Comment: @Akira I don't think he necessarily is trying to sort the lines once they have been imported. He just wants to detect where the words are and add spaces.

Comment: @Wold, I simply trusted the question title, in which "sort" is the first word. :) Well, not literally.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your problem is really about parsing and formatting rather than sorting?

To format text like this you could use a Scanner to easily match each QB like this

```
String text = "QB3Anderson, DerekACTTDS--INT--YDS--RTG0.0CARQB2Barkley, MattACTTDS0INT4YDS300RTG44.6PHIQB5Bethel-Thompson, McLeodACTTDS0INT0YDS0RTG0.0SF";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
scanner.useDelimiter("QB");
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String qb = "QB" + scanner.next();
    System.out.println(qb);
}
```

which will output:
QB3Anderson, DerekACTTDS--INT--YDS--RTG0.0CAR
QB2Barkley, MattACTTDS0INT4YDS300RTG44.6PHI
QB5Bethel-Thompson, McLeodACTTDS0INT0YDS0RTG0.0SF

Then for each qb string you could use String.subString() and String.indexOf() to do simple pattern matches on the fields you want eg.

```
String number = qb.substring(2, 3);
String name = qb.substring(3, qb.indexOf("ACT"));
String INT = qb.substring(qb.indexOf("INT") + 3, qb.indexOf("YDS") );
```

Once you have all your fields parsed then print them in the format and order you want